# Is it possible to have variable substitution in a nested heredoc?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, nested, heredoc

I have a bash script of this structure:

```
ssh user1@host <<EOF1
    var1="abc"
    echo \$var1

    su user2 <<EOF2
        var2="xyz"
        #echo var2 (how?)
        ..do something..
EOF2
EOF1
```

Now I'm able to define and access the variables inside the outer heredoc EOF1 as shown. Is it possible do the same inside inner heredoc EOF2?

**This is what I do in my script :** I execute a command inside the EOF2 as a different user, get the exit code of that command and store it in a variable for further checks inside EOF2 block. But I'm stuck in storing the exit code of command into a variable and accessing it later. Any other way of doing this would also be of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just add a backslash:

```
echo \\\$var2
```

which is transformed (within the outer heredoc) into:

```
echo \$var2
```

and finally inside the inner heredoc into:

```
echo $var2
```

Comment: What about using `var1` inside `EOF2`? Would `\$var1` be enough? Or does it need `\\\$var1`?